# How to formulate and deal with two different linear equations in Gurobi

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, gurobi

Working on an optimization problem formulated as an MIP where I have two decision variables `a[i,j] and b[u,v,x,y]`. I have a couple of equations `(EQ1,.., EQ10)`. For simplicity and abstraction levels I just mention `EQ1 and EQ2`.

For a special case I need to express this situation :

```
If x!=y and a[u,x] = 1 and a[v,y] =1 then 
consider linear equation EQ1 // EQ1 for the special case
otherwise consider EQ2.
```

Does any one know how to deal with this situation ? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: That's pretty much asking for all the tricks mentioned [here](https://download.aimms.com/aimms/download/manuals/AIMMS3OM_IntegerProgrammingTricks.pdf), which might be now easier to handle since gurobi introduced *general constraints* in version 7. **But:** that ```x!=y``` calls for trouble for non-discrete variables and you need some epsilon-based check.

Comment: Thanks a lot@sascha, I have to say that the link you shared is just amazing ! Back to x!=y, x and y belong to the same set of values and when x!=y then b[u,v,x,y] is not defined so I need to switch to EQ2. Could you elaborate more on general constraints and how I can use it?

Comment: I never used them. They are quite new. They **might** ease the way to formulate indicator-constraints and co. [docs](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.0/refman/constraints.html).

Comment: That's fine I will try to go through the doc and see how I can overcome this issue and share my solution right after. Thanks